# Android Databinding @{} vs @={}

Tags: android, android-databinding

I couldn't find the difference between
`@{}` vs `@={}` at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions).

What is the difference?

Comment: It is one way and two-way binding check here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: Thanks, it's there: "The @={} notation, which importantly includes the "=" sign, receives data changes to the property and listen to user updates at the same time."

Comment: The former is one-way, latter is two-way databinding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Data Binding, there are two types:

In **one-way data binding,** information flows in a single direction (read OR write). This type uses the `@{}` notation.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@{viewmodel.rememberMe}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{viewmodel.rememberMeChanged}"
/>
```

In **two-way data binding**, information flows in both directions (read AND write). This type uses the `@={}` notation, which importantly includes the "`=`" sign. It receives data changes to the property and listen to user updates at the same time.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/rememberMeCheckBox"
    android:checked="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"
/>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way):